# My line manager consistently never capitalizes my first name

Tags: new-manager

A coworker of mine has recently become my line manager after my previous LM changed teams. But ever since we’ve started interacting after I joined the team, when writing messages on Skype, he would not capitalize my first name. My name is a standard English name, is not a shortened version and everyone else writes it with a capital letter when addressing me.

I brought it up with him once before he became my line manager and asked if he could start capitalizing it when writing messages to me and he replied with a thumbs up. But still he kept doing the same.

To me this feels disrespectful (he is a bit more senior than I am). Our one on one relationship is not close either.

Does this happen to you in the workplace? Would you be bothered by this?

Comment: Does he do this with other people, or just you? Lots of people don't bother with proper punctuation when using instant message systems like Skype. Also, by any chance is your name more commonly an ordinary English word? If so, maybe it's being autocorrected to lowercase.

Comment: "Does this happen to you in the workplace? Would you be bothered by this?" Both generate opinionated answers.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? It's a valid question.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask: "avoid asking subjective questions where  every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”" I don't know how this hasn't been closed yet.

Answer (score 4):

> Does this happen to you in the workplace?

No

> Would you be bothered by this?

No.

Does he do the same thing toward the other workers ? If yes, then this is no reason to take it personally.

I don't think he means to disrespect you. It may just be that he skips the upper case because he types too fast and probably multitasks at the same time.

This is not really the battle you want to fight hard and take it all the way to his manager or HR.

---

Nowadays, it seems that on social media, some people often type with all lower-cased letters to go fast. Your boss may be one of them. :-)

When you asked him to type the first letter of your name with an upper case one, and he simply replied with a "**Thumbs up**" instead of saying "**Oh, I am sorry. It was typo. I will fix it the next time**". That tells you something about your boss' preferred way of communication. :-)

Comment: could also be a mobile issue. I hate capitalization on a touch keyboard. If the auto-correct does it for me, great. If it doesn't, I'm not going to fix it.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't happen to me, but if it's a regular enough occurrence and not just the occasional typo - yeah, I'd be irritate too.

So far, you've done the right thing - you've raised it with him in writing - if he still persists in doing it, *and you are willing to take this further, even though it might be a CLM (Career Limiting Move)* - then talk with HR, it's a simple request and it's the basic of common curtesy to spell your name correctly (and a capital letter at the beginning **is** part of spelling it correctly)

Comment: You'd really involve HR in capitalisation matters? That's a new level of not having better things to do :-/

Comment: @red-shield - disagree. Not spelling someone's name correctly (and proper capitalization is part of that) is a sign of disrespect. It's saying your name is so unimportant as to take the 5 seconds or so it would take to spell it properly.